# Does Jupyter Notebook use *significantly* more RAM than the terminal?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ram

Suppose I have a 100GB CSV file (`X.csv`), and I want to execute the following code:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.loadtext('X.csv', delimiter=',')
X = X @ X
```

Does Jupyter Notebook use *significantly* more RAM than the terminal? I know that Jupyter Notebook will keep `X` in memory even after executing the code, but does it use *significantly* more RAM while executing?

If Jupyter Notebook does use *significantly* more RAM, does it scale with `X`?

Edit: I know that matrix multiplication can be done without loading X into memory; the question is more to do with ram usage of Jupyter Notebook compared to ram usage of the terminal.

Comment: The question is a bit misplaced.  The Jupyter Notebook has a relatively high overhead to begin with, but it's using exactly the same Python interpreter that you use at a command line.  The Python code will use exactly the same RAM in both cases.  In the Jupyter case, it's just that the Python interpreter remains open.

Comment: @TimRoberts That is what I had in mind. So Jupyter Notebook will use exactly the same RAM as the terminal + overdraft of running Jupyter Notebook, which doesn't scale with `X`.

Comment: @TimRoberts To be clear: there wouldn't be any code where Jupyter Notebook would keep garbage in memory while executing, but the terminal wouldn't?

Comment: I'll say this: IF you opened a Python interpreter, and typed into it everything you typed into a Jupyter Notebook without closing it, then the Python interpreter memory use would be the same.  Jupyter itself doesn't keep any Python information.  It's just routine command lines and output to and from the interpreter.